# C# regular expression to NSRegularExpression

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following regular expression that gets me the table name and column details of a create index statement:

```
        Regex r = new Regex(@"create\s*index.*?\son\s*\[?(?<table>[\s\w]*\w)\]?\s*\((?:(?<cname>[\s\d\w\[\]]*),?)*\)", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

I would like to use this in Objective-C. I have tried the following:

```
            NSError * error = nil;
            NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern: @"create\\s*index.*?\\son\\s*\\[?([\\s\\w]*\\w)\\]?\\s*\\((?:([\\s\\d\\w\\[\\]]*),?)*\\)"
                                                                                   options: NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive | NSRegularExpressionSearch
                                                                                     error: &error];
            if(nil != error)
            {
                NSLog(@"Error is: %@. %@", [error localizedDescription], error);
            }

            NSRange rangeOfFirstMatch = [regex rangeOfFirstMatchInString: createStatement options:0 range: NSMakeRange(0, [createStatement length])];

            NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString: createStatement
                                              options: 0
                                                range: NSMakeRange(0, [createStatement length])];
```

Which partially works. It gives me three ranges. The first one contains the entire string and the second one contains the table name. The problem is that the third one is empty.

Anyone have any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Edit: The string I'm trying to parse is: CREATE INDEX cardSetIndex ON [card] (cardSetId ASC)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you seem to  have is that the second capture group is being overwritten by the last itteration of `(?: )*`. Since its optional, its always blank.

Your regex:

```
 create\s*index.*?\son\s*
 \[?
     ( [\s\w]*\w )
 \]?\s*
 \(
     (?:
        ( [\s\d\w\[\]]* )
        ,?
     )*
 \)
```

Change it to:

```
 create\s*index.*?\son\s*
 \[?
    ( [\s\w]*\w )
 \]?
 \s*
 \(
    (
      (?: [\s\d\w\[\]]* ,? )*
    )
 \)
```

Compressed and escaped:

```
create\\s*index.*?\\son\\s*\\[?([\\s\\w]*\\w)\\]?\\s*\\(((?:[\\s\\d\\w\\[\\]]*,?)*)\\)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is sort of vague about what you actually want to grab, and that regex is quite gnarly, so I wasn't able to glean it from that.

`CREATE\s*INDEX\s*(\w+)\s*ON\s*(\[\w+\])\s*\((.+)\)`

That will grab the table name in group 1, the ON property in group 2, and the following property after that in group 3.